# kfree_skb() unexpected behavior

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, kernel-module

I have some trouble using kfree_skb. The below three lines of code behave in a strange way,

```
printk(KERN_ALERT"1 - SKB user: %d", atomic_read(&skb->users));
kfree_skb(skb);
printk(KERN_ALERT"2 - SKB user: %d", atomic_read(&skb->users));
```

I expect that the second *printk* causes a kernel panic since I freed the [skb](http://vger.kernel.org/%7Edavem/skb.html), but it does not. The output of these lines are as follows;

```
1 - SKB user: 1
2 - SKB user: 2
```

What is the point that I missed?

The second output was incorrect. It is as follows:

```
2 - SKB user: 1
```

Comment: I think you just lucky you have the valid pointer to arbitrary data here.

Answer (score 0):

When you free the [skb](http://vger.kernel.org/%7Edavem/skb.html), there is a high chance that it gets allocated in another thread.

Just think about this:

```
Thread 1:

printk(KERN_ALERT"1 - SKB user: %d", atomic_read(&skb->users));
kfree_skb
-------> scheduled out  

Thread 2:
alloc_skb()
//inc user count (whatever the kernel call)
-------> Scheduled out
```

Then now back in Thread 1,

```
printk(KERN_ALERT"2 - SKB user: %d", atomic_read(&skb->users));
```

Now there is a very high likehood that you can get user count 2.

Since skbs are allocated from the slab cache, it highly likely that just now the freed skb gets allocated first.

Comment: There is a mistake in the output section, I am sorry, I have corrected it.

Comment: Even if that is the case , answer wouldn't change. Just that "//inc user count (whatever the kernel call)"  case wouldnt arise

Answer (score 0):

First let's have a quick look at the `kfree_skb()` function. The code has been changed at v4.13, but it is still behaves the same:

****Before v4.13** (when the question has been published):**

```
void kfree_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (unlikely(!skb))
        return;
    if (likely(atomic_read(&skb->users) == 1))
        smp_rmb();
    else if (likely(!atomic_dec_and_test(&skb->users)))
        return;
    trace_kfree_skb(skb, __builtin_return_address(0));
    __kfree_skb(skb);
}
```

**After v4.13:**

```
void kfree_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (!skb_unref(skb))
        return;

    trace_kfree_skb(skb, __builtin_return_address(0));
    __kfree_skb(skb);
}

static inline bool skb_unref(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (unlikely(!skb))
        return false;
    if (likely(refcount_read(&skb->users) == 1))
        smp_rmb();
    else if (likely(!refcount_dec_and_test(&skb->users)))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

In both cases, I've noticed that when you call `kfree_skb()`, the [skb](http://vger.kernel.org/%7Edavem/skb.html) does get freed (`__kfree_skb()` is been called). However, I've also noticed in both cases that if `skb->users` was 1 before calling `kfree_skb()`, it would stay 1 even after calling `kfree_skb()`.

kfree_skb() does free the skb when the skb should be freed, but it won't protect you from double freeing the skb. It seems it has been made on purpose in order to avoid the use of unnecessary atomic operations (you can find this comment somewhere in the skbuff.h code):

```
/*
 * If users == 1, we are the only owner and can avoid redundant atomic changes.
 */
```

Nevertheless, you can see that in `__dev_kfree_skb_irq()` the behavior is just as you expected it to be (if `skb->users` was 1 before calling `__dev_kfree_skb_irq()`, `skb->users` is set to 0 has expected):

```
void __dev_kfree_skb_irq(struct sk_buff *skb, enum skb_free_reason reason)
{
    unsigned long flags;

    if (unlikely(!skb))
        return;

    if (likely(refcount_read(&skb->users) == 1)) {
        smp_rmb();
        refcount_set(&skb->users, 0);
    } else if (likely(!refcount_dec_and_test(&skb->users))) {
        return;
    }
    get_kfree_skb_cb(skb)->reason = reason;
    local_irq_save(flags);
    skb->next = __this_cpu_read(softnet_data.completion_queue);
    __this_cpu_write(softnet_data.completion_queue, skb);
    raise_softirq_irqoff(NET_TX_SOFTIRQ);
    local_irq_restore(flags);
}
```